# הציל את העם Versus  הציל אתכם

Tags: parashas-yisro

אשר הציל אתכם מיד מצרים ומיד פרעה אשר הציל את העם מתחת יד מצרים

Why the Difference and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where saved on two levels hence the use of two languages. One is the actual Golus living in a strange land, and the second is the working of the Jews as slaves.This like the Posuk says:

כי גר יהיה זרעך בארץ לא להם, ועבדום וענו אותם

That is first you will be strangers in a strange land and then and only then,you will suffer as a slave.

But Moshe and Aharon who were from the Shevet Levi who only had one aspect of this Golus the Strangers in a strange land, and not the slavery, so Moshe and Aharon it says "אשר הציל אתכם מיד מצרים" as you where saved from the Hands of Mitzrayim meaning the Slavery. But when Yisro is talking to them about the rest of Klal Yisroel he say **מתחת** יד מצרים to add the extra aspect of  מתחת that is ועבדום וענו אותם the slavery